# In NLTK pos_tag, why "hello" is classified as Noun?

Tags: python, nlp, nltk

I've tried

```
text = nltk.word_tokenize("hello, my name is John")
words = nltk.pos_tag(text)

for w in words:
    print "%s = %s" % (w[0], w[1])
```

And I got:

```
hello = NN
, = ,
my = PRP$
name = NN
is = VBZ
John = NNP
```

Comment: The reason it does this is that *computers cannot understand English.*

Comment: @Ben @larsmans @Joce I expected an interjection. @kindall At least, computers can understand words and look for their definition. But seems like the tagger give priority to the "hello" as noun.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to the Penn Treebank tagset, *hello* is definitely an interjection and is consistently tagged UH.  The problem you're running into is that the taggers that NLTK ships with were most likely trained on the part of the Wall Street Journal section of the Penn Treebank that is available for free, which unfortunately for you contains zero occurrences of the word *hello* and only three words tagged UH (interjection). If you want to tag spoken text, you'll need to train your tagger on the whole Penn Treebank, which includes something like 3 million words of spoken English.

By the way, the NLTK taggers won't always call *hello* a noun -- try tagging "don't hello me!" or "he said hello".

Answer (score 2):

NLTK use it own tagger to tag part of speech.

But the accuracy will vary from text to text. It is because the tagger was trained using a corpus provided by NLTK itself. The corpus could be about anything.

The corpus is not similar to your text, then the tagger will fail to tag your text because the context, style is all very different.

You can train your own tagger if you got the time to do it.

Computer are not human, computer just do what we told them to do. So in order to make it do it properly, you should teach them properly to achieve best result.

Comment: Can you point me from where the default tagger take hello as noun? Did you know that? I'm surprised with that, since it's not common (even if it's correct).

Comment: If there are no occurrences in the training, I think the default is to tag the word as a noun.

Answer (score 2):

Look in any dictionary and you will find hello defined as a "noun" (e.g. Longman). It's often described as an "exclamation" or "interjection" but the tag "noun" is not incorrect.

Comment: I know, but I would say that unusually we classify hello as noun. But in essence it is an interjection. When you say "One Hello" it is a noun that are naming the utterance or interjection "Hello". So, I'd expect an Interjection tag not a noun. But seems like I need to train my tagger, since this default tagger take some wrong decisions.

Comment: Yes. I was trying to make the point that the tagger wasn't really making a *wrong* decision (not that you said it did). Someone said "The reason it does this is that computers cannot understand English." suggesting that the answer is *wrong*. I was correcting that point. Yes, more tagged training data will help.