# How can I train NLTK on the entire Penn Treebank corpus?

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, corpus, tagged-corpus

I was originally using the following Penn Treebank tagger from NLTK:

```
POS_Tagger = UnigramTagger(treebank.tagged_sents(), backoff=DefaultTagger('NN'))
```

However, this falls short on spoken text. For instance, "hello" is not recognized as an interjection when it should be. I read from here ([In NLTK pos_tag, why “hello” is classified as Noun?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5932227/in-nltk-pos-tag-why-hello-is-classified-as-noun)) that if I want to tag spoken text, I'll "need to train the tagger on the whole Penn Treebank, which includes something like 3 million words of spoken English." The question I now have is **HOW** can I do this? I've been here ([Penn Treebank Project](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~treebank/)) but can't find anything on it.

If training on the whole Penn Treebank is too difficult, what would be an alternative? I'm considering the Brown corpus instead however the POS tags are different, making me have to rewrite other sections of the program.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately the Penn Treebank is only available for a hefty fee through the [Linguistic Data Consortium](http://catalog.ldc.upenn.edu/LDC99T42).  If your needs are non-commercial you might be able to find an academic who can grant you access to it.

Alternatively you could create your own silver-standard (as opposed to gold-standard) data by running existing POS taggers like the [ClearNLP tools](https://code.google.com/p/clearnlp/) or the [Stanford CoreNLP tools](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/corenlp.shtml) on your some other data (news articles, Brown, Wikipedia, etc...)  Then you can take this tagged data and train the NLTK taggers.  Of course if you need data that is better oriented for speech, you might want to look at the Switchboard corpus.  It looks like there is a [version with some POS and syntactic annotation](http://groups.inf.ed.ac.uk/switchboard/download.html) available through the Creative Commons license.

Answer (score 3):

You may want to consider the American National Corpus. Although not all of it is freely available, a substantial subset is (about 14 million words). That part is known as the "OANC" ("O" for "Open"). It is tagged with Penn Treebank POS tags.

It also includes higher-level annotations, such as paragraph, sentence, and noun and verb "chunks", which you may or may not need, but could of course just ignore.

See http://www.anc.org/.

Answer (score 1):

The Penn Treebank corpus in NLTK is only a sample of the real Penn Treebank, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User:Alvations/NLTK_cheatsheet/CorporaReaders#Penn_Tree_Bank

The sample contains only 3000+ sentences while the brown corpus in NLTK contains over 50,000. Unless you've access to the whole PTB, it's better to use other corpora.